# In PrimeNG how to apply conditional coloring to rows in tree table component

Tags: angular, primeng

I am new to PrimeNG, and using a tree table component in my angular 2 application.

I want to apply the entire row (tr) with different style based on conditions. I tried ngStyle and ngClass. But it is not working.

```
<p:treetable id="coloring" var="car" [value]="{treeTableController}"
[ngStyle] ="{{car.year le 1975 ? 'colored' : null}}">
<p:columnheaderText="Year">{car.year}</p:column>
<p:columnheaderText="Name">{car.name}</p:column>
</p:treetable>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: btw, you talk about PrimeNG but your code is PrimeFaces..  You talk about a tree table but your code is a datatable... Please create **good** questions. See also [ask]

Answer (score 0):

use **[ngClass]/[ngStyle]** instead of rowStyleClass it may help you as below:

```
[ngStyle]="{'height': splitterHeight + 'px'}"

[ngClass]="mode == 'multiple' ? 'multipleEditorModal' : 'NoClass'"
```